# Adding Calendar and Time to Forms

Tags: php, forms, date, time, calendar

Introduction

---

Hello. I am a newbie to `PHP` programming. I have know the basics and now I am into developing a web application from it. I trying to implement the following functionality(It's a `ASP.NET calendar`),

[image]

Explanation

---

In the Date of Birth option, when the user clicks the calendar icon shown, the following calendar shows up and the user can select the date from it.

What have I done?

---

Sorry, but my knowledge for now is nothing more than this,

```
<input name="todo" type="text" />

<input name="time" type="button" />
```

My Requirements

---

I need the same functionality for my web application for time and date.

I would be very thankful for the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had to answer my question myself as I found out the answer. Its implemented [here](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php).

However, I am not marking my answer as selected answer. I await for better answers as time functionality is still needed by me. Thankyou.